# Add a button to a column header in Telerik RadView

Tags: wpf, telerik

Is there a way to put a button in the column header of the Telerik RadGridView component for WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/gridview-styling-column-headers.html

You'll want to create a new custom `GridViewHeaderCellTemplate` and put your button in there.

> GridViewHeaderCellTemplate - the ControlTemplate, applied to the GridViewCell.

Also see: http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radgridview-styles-and-templates-templates-structure.html#GridViewHeaderCell